# Trouble converting JSON to pandas. All of the data is contained in one row. How do I unpack it?

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested, flatten

I'm trying to convert a JSON file into a pandas dataframe, however, while the columns look correct all of the data is contained in one row instead of my intention for it to be a time series with the index being the 'Fiscal Year'

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import urllib.request, json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://api.gurufocus.com/public/user/f97abc68a0f96617ccea854faeff6db:ca86e5ff8d37550212f9c7d45645d413/stock/WMT/financials')

content = response.read()

data = json.loads(content.decode('utf8'))

data = (data['financials']['annuals'])

data = json_normalize(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data)
print(df)
```

The output appears to be a df with the columns looking correct, but only one row and there should be at least 30 unique years for each column. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you include a sample of the data for easier replication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is far beyond what pandas automatic Json processing can do: your json is a complex structure with up to 2 key levels and only there lists of size 30 or 31.

At that point, forget `json_normalize` and start manual parsing.

First pass, flatten the dictionary:

```
def flatten(data):
    flat = {}
    for k, v in data.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            for j, u in flatten(v).items():
                flat[k+'-'+j] = u
        else:
            flat[k] = v
    return flat

data2 = flatten(data)
```

Control that we now have a dict of lists, and control the sizes of lists:

```
c = collections.Counter()
for k,v in data2.items():
    if isinstance(v, list):
        c[len(v)] += 1
    else:
        print('============', k, type(v))
```

Ok, only lists of 31 elements except one: add a `None` to make all lists equal length:

```
for k,v in data2.items():
    if len(v) == 30:
        v.append(None)
```

We now have a dictionary of lists of equal length: this is suitable to build a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Comment: Thanks for reviewing Serge. I plugged in your code immediately after the "flat=" line and received the following error msg... NameError: name 'collections' is not defined

Comment: `collections` is a package from the standard library. Just add `import collections` before using it.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Grateful!